# 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int when trying to make lambda from aws-cli

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to setup github actions to autodeploy lambdas when pushed to main but when i run
`aws lambda create-function --function-name "helloWorld" --runtime nodejs20.x --role arn:aws:iam:... --handler "helloWorld.handler" --code fileb://helloWorld.zip`
I keep getting the error
`'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`
the zip file just contains helloworld.js
which just has
`export const handler = async (event) => { const response = { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'), }; return response; };`

(if it helps the zip file is made using `zip -r "helloWorld.zip" ".\helloWorld.js"`)

I tried changing the command to
`aws lambda create-function --function-name "helloWorld" --runtime nodejs20.x --role arn:aws:iam... --handler "helloWorld.handler" --code file://helloWorld.zip`

but that just gave an error of
`Error parsing parameter '--code': Unable to load paramfile (helloWorld.zip), text contents could not be decoded.  If this is a binary file, please use the fileb:// prefix instead of the file:// prefix.`

Answer (score 0):

To use a zip file as the lambda code, you need to use --zip-file myfile.zip instead of --code myfile.zip